# Executing jar from within compiled program

Tags: java, jar, runtime

I have a launcher I'm creating as a mini side project and I'm trying to execute a jar file. I figured out how to execute a exe. Heres the code:

```
mineshaft.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String mhome = System.getProperty("user.home") + "";
            try {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar .mhome+ \\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\minecraft.exe");
            }

            catch (Exception a) {

            }

        }
    });
```

Ive searched everywhere, and everyone says this code works, but it won't for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: Put a a.printStacktrace() in your catch statement. Are you getting any errors/exceptions?

Comment: .mhome+ doesn't belong inside the quoted string.

Comment: Is `minecraft.exe` actually a jar file?  Typically executable jar files have a .jar extension.

Comment: oh wow meant mineshaft.jar sorry. I copied some code from other sections of my program

Comment: That wasn't the answer though... Hopefully someone can help me

Comment: @opiop65, we are helping. Read the comments. Read bmargulies's comment about .mhome+. Also, print your exception. If an exception is being thrown you will never know what the problem is because you aren't printing it. Try running the exact command from the command line where you are running your java program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JarInputStream stream = null;

try {   

  File jar = new File("/path/to/jar.jar");
  stream = new JarInputStream(new FileInputStream(jar));
  String mainClass = stream.getManifest().getMainAttributes().getValue("Main-class");
  ClassLoader loader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] { jar.toURI().toURL() }, getClass().getClassLoader);
  Class<?> main = Class.forName(mainClass, loader);
  main.getDeclaredMethod("main", String[].class).invoke(null, null);

} finally {
  stream.close();
}
```

km1's answer is simpler if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

First, your command is wrong. `.mhome+` ?
Make sure your command is correct. From a command prompt enter the following:

```
java -jar .mhome\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\minecraft.exe
```

That's essentially what you are running.

Also, PRINT YOUR STACKTRACE. Especially during development.

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String mhome = System.getProperty("user.home") + "";
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar " + mhome + "\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft\\minecraft.jar");
        }

        catch (Exception a) {
             a.printStrackTrace();
        }

    }
```